# How to use Guillotine (crop image) with Aurelia JS? [ERROR]

Tags: jquery, aurelia, jquery-guillotine

I'm trying to use [Guillotine](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine), a plugin for cropping images. I have a modal component which loads the image that I want to crop. In the modal class, I import **jQuery**, and I'm trying to import Guillotine, but I'm receiving the following message:

> "the function guillotine does not exist."

**Guillotine.js** is at the root of components, together with jQuery. I have also used NPM to install.

Here's my class:

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'guillotine';

export class ModalCrop{
    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) display = 'none';

    created() {
        $('#thepicture').guillotine({ width: 400, height: 300 });
    }
}
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend loading jQuery and any jQuery widgets using script tags. These things just weren't made for use in a modular environment and so we have to fight with them to try and make them work.

So I say, why fight them?

You can still use npm to install the widget if you'd like, just load it using a script tag.

Or, if you're using the Aurelia CLI, simply add this stuff to the "prepend" section of `vendor-bundle`.

Check this example for a different jQuery widget I wrote for another question. It uses script tags: https://gist.run/?id=6e4a6ea77751ae9c69b178eb51105137

Comment: Sorry, I have got confused... How could I call the Gullotine methods with script tags?

Comment: The same you have for years. You load jQuery and Guillotine using script tags. That makes jQuery available globally and Guillotine available on the jQuery object.  there's no need to use import statements in this case. Just check out the example gist I posted that shows jquery and the widget being loaded with script tags in `index.html` and then used in `app.js`. Also, look at how I'm using the `ref` custom attribute instead of an `id` on the element I'm applying the widget to. This will make your code more reusable.